# Python - Boto3 - dict has no attribute 'InstanceId'

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I'm having the user enter a list of AWS instance IDs. I'm using Pyton 3 and boto to print out info for the instance, and then delete it.

I get this error when I try to run the script:

```
File ".\aws_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print("Instance ID: ", instance.id)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Here is my sample code:

```
import boto3
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
instance_id = 'i-076361b30ee404bb4'
instance = ec2.describe_instances(
    InstanceIds=[instance_id]
    )['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
# Add instance info to a dictionary
ec2info = defaultdict()
print("Instance ID: ", instance.id)
```

If I can get at the instance ID I will access the others I need to print like this:

```
ec2info[instance.id] = {
    'Instance ID': instance.id,
    'Type': instance.instance_type,
    'State': instance.state['Name'],
    'Private IP': instance.private_ip_address,
    'Public IP': instance.public_ip_address,
    'Launch Time': instance.launch_time
    }
```

And print them out. Why can't I get to the instance.id value? How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`describe_instances()` [returns a `dict`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances).  Use:

```
instance["id"]
```

This uses `instance.__getitem__("id")` to do the key lookup.  What you're doing is an attribute lookup, which is different.